# не получается импортировать пакет implicit

Tags: python

Пробывала импортировать пакет в Jupyter Notebook так:
!pip install implicit
и так :
!pip install implicit==0.2.13
ошибок не выводит , но и ничего не устанавливает!
Следовательно import implicit не работает.

Comment: Так а что пишет? Приведите вывод команды в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install implicit
```

https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/#How-to-use-Pip-from-the-Jupyter-Notebook